# How do I connect to another process over the network at home?

Tags: networking

So I have this server and a client application that I made using RakNet. Locally, on one machine, I just connect to localhost and matching ports.

However, what IP do I connect to when I want to connect to another machine that is still within the same network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming no firewall and ports open you just connect to the machine's local IP.
You can obtain that by running the following command from a shell / command prompt on the machine you want to connect to:

Linux/OSX:

```
ifconfig
```

Windows:

```
ipconfig
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! :D